# Flutter: It looks like pub.dartlang.org is having some trouble

Tags: flutter

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
dani@DanielRodriguezs-MacBook-Pro my_rents % flutter pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
It looks like pub.dartlang.org is having some trouble.
Pub will wait for a while before trying to connect again.
Got socket error trying to find package flutter_google_places at https://pub.dartlang.org.
```

With `flutter upgrade`:

```
Building flutter tool...
Got socket error trying to find package completion at https://pub.dartlang.org.
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
```

2 days ago it was working perfectly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing Bitdefender fixed the issue in my case but it could be related to other antivirus/firewalls.
In my case this is a company laptop so I can't be sure what other security layers could affect this

Answer (score 0):

You were probably not connected to the Internet

#### Solution:

Check that you are connected to the Internet.

> Note :  If the problem persists, check that you don't have an antivirus
> program or VPN that prevents packages from loading.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your antivirus or exclude the follow web url

```
pub.darlang.org
```

In Avast for Mac you can do it here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was just because of slow network connection the minute I switched network the dependencies where added.
I removed the packages and added it again on both network  just to test theory and it worked on the faster network connection.